# GetUtcDate in insert statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to have the current date and time inserted into SQL Server.
I tried the following method but it didn't work.

```
insertstatement = "insert into tablename(sqldate) values (?)"
values = ('getutcdate()')
cursor.execute(insertstatement , values)
cnxn.commit()
```

I am getting the following error:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I need to use the SQL Server time only because the code is getting executed at different servers and the timezones and need to use a standard time accurate to milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to insert SQL datetime, then the time should be got at SQL Server, so your code should looks like this

```
insertstatement = "insert into tablename(sqldate) values (getutcdate())"
cur.execute(insertstatement)
cnxn.commit()
```

Try to use `GETUTCDATE()` function. Let me show an example:

```
insert into tablename(sqldate) values (GETUTCDATE())
```

In addition, your type of table column should be `DateTime`. For example:

```
DECLARE @FooTable TABLE 
(
      StartDate DateTime
)

INSERT INTO @FooTable
(
    StartDate,
)
VALUES
(
    GETUTCDATE(),
)

SELECT StartDate FROM @FooTable
```

[MSDN has a great description about GETUTCDATE() and possible use cases.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @star_kid sorry for my misunderstanding, please, see the updated reply.